# CakeDC Search Plugin generated duplicate IDs in URL

Tags: cakephp, search, plugins, cakedc

I am using the `DC search Plugin` in several Cake projects and generally it works very well. But for one of my pages I have the problem that the searches blows up the URL.
The starting URL is somethin like:

`/lessons/abrechnung/10`

When the search is used the resulting URL is something like:

`/lessons/abrechnung/10/10/10/datumab:01.02.2014/datumbis:25.02.2014`

The search itselfs works well - I get the results filtered by the search criteria.
But: As you can see the ID value is duplicated each time you search. This continues and after 3 or 4 searches the URL contains 50 or 100 times the ID.

How can I avoid this?

I guess this would happen on all actions where I have unnamed params in the URL - but I am not sure about this. BTW: The search params are NOT getting duplicated.

EDIT:

I use cakePHP 2.4.0 and Version 2.3 of teh Search Plugin.

Using 'paramType' => 'querystring' didn't help. But I see now that there is something wrong with my Session-Handling. I will check that and give further feedback.

Comment: Use the recommended query strings instead of the deprecated and flawed named params. As for your issue, you need to post some code (e.g. from the Form create part). Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Thank you! The querystring-option does not help. But I think I have some other problems with the session handling. I will check that...

Answer (score 0):

My guess: Your form setup is incorrect.

Do not interfere with the URL of the posted form.
So use

```
echo $this->Form->create();
```

without modifying action/url keys.
This way the form will automatically post to itself, and the Search plugin auto-adds the search params in the PRG redirect.
Then there will be no duplication of passed params or alike.

Independent from this it is still better to use the query strings here (and for pagination then as well, of course).